# Harry Potter Fanfic where Harry is sent to an alternate dimension where Tom Riddle is good

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I know this fic is either on AO3 or Fanfic.

It’s a Harry Potter story, I can’t remember if it had a set ship or not.
The background is;

- Harry is somehow transported to an alternate dimension.
- In this dimension Tom Riddle never becomes Voldemort and he marries Myrtle. - I’m pretty sure he’s some sort of famous position (edit: Tom works at Hogwarts as a teacher)
- They find a young Harry (as he was de-aged) wondering alone during a broom flight. He’s badly injured and all he can say is his name: “I am Harry.”
- He seems “not all the way there”?
- I am not 100% sure on this; but I think Lily and James are not married in the story
- When Tom and Myrtle found him he was injured. I think it was from the final battle, or left over injuries from his uncle?? I’m not to sure.
- Important Note: Harry can’t speak? I can’t remember if he decides not to or if he physically can not. But while he wasn’t “awake” his body/mind wouldn’t allow him to speak. But he still communicated with everyone, even if it seemed like he was younger than he looked.

But the story actually starts at his sorting, when Harry “wakes up”. He doesn’t remember any of the time his body has spent in this universe, and vividly remembers Tom as Voldemort. I can’t remember it exactly, but it seems as if Tom and Myrtle have another child- possibly adopted as well?Who was originally going to go into Hufflepuff, but decided to go into Slytherin with Harry after arguing with the sorting hat.

When they get to the common room Harry acts without reacting when Snape shows up and assumes a combat position in the shadows. Snape apologize for startling Harry and then praises him for his reflexes.

During class when’re they are asked to use a certain spell Harry can do it; I believe that’s exempt from his no talking rule, if not he does it wordlessly.

Harry goes searching for answers in the library, where a system is set up for article about the subject, article Le close to the subject, and relating light up in certain colors. At one point Harry Apparates out of the castle and everyone freaks out because he has a tracking charm on him.

Comment: To clarify: AO3 is Archive of Our Own, correct? And Fanfic is fanfiction.net?

Comment: Yes. AO3 is Archive Of Our Own and Fanfic is FanFiction.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fic is "[Warping Circumstances"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2862220/1/Warping-Circumstances) by Deritine on fanfiction.net.. 
I recognized the story you were describing, and this is it. :)

> The horcruxes are destroyed- the bits of soul latched on to Harry's own. But killing himself only sends Harry to an alternate dimension, this one desperately vulnerable to the dark soul he carries.

....

> "Why they are even letting you be sorted…
>   it's a crying shame. You aren't capable of this level of work…"
>   McGonagall mutters to herself before she guides Harry to sit on the
>   stool and places the hat over Harry's head. The brim falls down
>   over even his nose. Harry raises his hand to touch the leather brim
>   but has his hand gently swatted away. "Leave that dear, just sit
>   still for a second." Harry is completely lost, but he lets the hat
>   start to sift through his head. Until he can figure out what is going
>   on, Harry decides to act as innocent as possible and wait to gather
>   more information.

....

> "You don't know either, isn't that right?"
>   The boy sneers, leaning in. "I bet I know just as much as you do.
>   He's so retarded the only things he can say are spell incantations
>   and his name, over and over. 'Harry. I'm Harry. Harry. Harry!'"
>   A hand grabs the back of the boy's robe and pulls him back.